# How to check if file has 0kb stream with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have bunch of `webm` files. Most of them are okay (video + audio stream). Some of them somehow have 2 streams, but audio stream is 0 kb. Files came from mediaserver, so I cannot change this.

I'm doing a lot of work with these files (trim, scale video, merge etc) with script. But these files causes errors. Example (simplified command without video-related filters):

`ffmpeg -y -i file1.webm -i file2.webm -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge[a]"  -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.opus`

File `file1.webm` has empty audio stream, `file2.webm` has normal audio stream. File `output.opus` is empty and has size 137 bytes.
Output command is https://pastebin.com/57BMDGWU
It contains these related messages:

> [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x42ec380] No channel layout for input 1
>
> [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x42ec380] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels

ffprobe shows there is stream:
`ffprobe -i file1.webm -show_streams -select_streams a -loglevel error`
https://pastebin.com/VR9EV0xm

Question is, if there is empty audio stream, how to.. ignore it and get non-empty streams to output?